# how to parse data after equal sign ="title 1"?

Tags: php, parsing, preg-match

I have a string as follow:

```
$value[0]='#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="title 1"  tvg-logo="./Logo1.png" group-title="groupTitle1",title 1';
```

I want to get data of tvg-name=, tvg-logo=,group-title= and another value after the last "," which is `title 1` in this case. I want to place those data as variables for later use. could any one tell me best way to do it ?

Comment: `preg_match('/(.*?)="(.*?)"/', ...)` would be one very quick/dirty way

Comment: your PHP code is incorrect, plz fix it that we can try to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example without using `preg_match` but should get you the expected result

```
<?php
function scrape_value($data, $key){
    $start = $key.'="';
    $end = '"';
    $data = stristr($data, $start); // Stripping all data from before $start
    $data = substr($data, strlen($start));  // Stripping $start
    $stop = stripos($data, $end);   // Getting the position of the $end of the data to scrape
    $data = substr($data, 0, $stop);    // Stripping all data from after and including the $end of the data to scrape
    return $data;   // Returning the scraped data from the function
}
$value[0] = '#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="title 1"  tvg-logo="./Logo1.png" group-title="groupTitle1",title 1';
echo scrape_value($value[0], 'tvg-name'); echo '<br />';
echo scrape_value($value[0], 'tvg-logo'); echo '<br />';
echo scrape_value($value[0], 'group-title'); echo '<br />';
echo substr($value[0],strrpos($value[0],',')+1);
?>
```

Result for tvg-name = `title 1`

Result for tvg-logo = `./Logo1.png`

Result for group-title = `groupTitle1`

Result for last value = `title 1`